# How to set multiple textures on same mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 3D. I am instantiating two gameobjects from resources from one single mesh.

Here is my code for setting the textures:

```
public static void EquipItem(Dictionary<string, object> permissions)
{
    if (permissions.Count == 0)
        return;

    ItemsTemplate iTemplate = ItemsHandler.itemsTemplate.Find(x => x.id == Convert.ToInt32(permissions["itemId"]));
    SlotType slotType = iTemplate.slot_type;
    CharacterData charData = Character.characterDetails[permissions["characterId"].ToString()];

    if(Convert.ToBoolean(permissions["allowedToEquip"]) == false)
    {
        if(Convert.ToInt32(permissions["characterId"]) == Character.characterId)
            Character.RecursiveFindChild(GameObject.Find("UI/Window (Character)/Content/Character Content/Equip Slots/").transform, slotType.ToString()).GetComponent<UIEquipSlot>().Unassign();
    }
    else
    {
        if(iTemplate.weapon_type == WeaponType.NotAWeapon){

        //Record added in clients ram about equiped items.
        Character.characterDetails[permissions["characterId"].ToString()].characterEquipedItems.Add(
        new CharacterEquipedItems(
            slotType,
            iTemplate
        ));

        //Applying visual appearence on the character
        DynamicCharacterAvatar charAv = GameObject.Find("CharactersOnline/"+ permissions["characterId"]).GetComponent<DynamicCharacterAvatar>();
        UMAWardrobeRecipe wardrobeRecipe = Resources.Load("Wardrobe/" + iTemplate.model) as UMAWardrobeRecipe;

        charAv.SetSlot(wardrobeRecipe);
        charAv.BuildCharacter();

        Dictionary<string, UMATextRecipe> allEquipedWardrobeRecipes = charAv.WardrobeRecipes;

        //To do - Add items stats to character stats.
        } else {
            GameObject CharacterGameObject = GameObject.Find("CharactersOnline/"+ permissions["characterId"]);
            //Loads the Weapon gameobject.
            GameObject WeaponGameObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Wardrobe/Weapons/" + iTemplate.model)) as GameObject;
            if (iTemplate.texture != null)
            {
                foreach(Material mat in WeaponGameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterials)
                {
                    mat.color = Color.white;
                    mat.SetTexture("_MainTex", Resources.Load("Wardrobe/Weapons/" + iTemplate.texture + "/" + iTemplate.model + "_" + mat.name + "_AlbedoTransparency") as Texture);
                    mat.SetTexture("_MetallicGlossMap", Resources.Load("Wardrobe/Weapons/" + iTemplate.texture + "/" + iTemplate.model + "_" + mat.name + "_MetallicSmoothness") as Texture);
                    mat.SetTexture("_BumpMap", Resources.Load("Wardrobe/Weapons/" + iTemplate.texture + "/" + iTemplate.model + "_" + mat.name + "_Normal") as Texture);
                    mat.SetTexture("_OcclusionMap", Resources.Load("Wardrobe/Weapons/" + iTemplate.texture + "/" + iTemplate.model + "_" + mat.name + "_AO") as Texture);
                }                   
            }

            //Search for the holders in the character
            GameObject MainHand = Character.RecursiveFindChild(CharacterGameObject.transform, "mixamorig:RightHandIndex2");
            GameObject OffHand = Character.RecursiveFindChild(CharacterGameObject.transform, "mixamorig:LeftHandIndex2");
            switch (iTemplate.slot_type)
            {
                case SlotType.MainHand:
                    GameObject MainHandWeapon = Instantiate(WeaponGameObject, MainHand.transform);
                    MainHandWeapon.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f,0.05f,0f);
                    MainHandWeapon.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(-45f, 0f, -70f));
                    MainHandWeapon.transform.localScale = Character.RaceEquipItemSizeModifier(charData.characterRace, charData.characterGender, MainHandWeapon.transform);
                    break;
                case SlotType.OffHand:
                    GameObject OffHandWeapon = Instantiate(WeaponGameObject, OffHand.transform);
                    OffHandWeapon.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f,0f,0.05f);
                    OffHandWeapon.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 70f));
                    OffHandWeapon.transform.localScale = Character.RaceEquipItemSizeModifier(charData.characterRace, charData.characterGender, OffHandWeapon.transform);
                    break;
                case SlotType.Shield:                        
                    GameObject Shield = Instantiate(WeaponGameObject, OffHand.transform);
                    //Shield.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(180f, -60f, 0f));
                    //Shield.transform.localScale += Character.RaceEquipItemSizeModifier(charData.characterRace, charData.characterGender, CharacterGameObject.transform);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }           
        }

    }
}
```

However it sets the textures of the last instantiated gameobject. Is it even possible to have different textures on multiple gameobjects instantiated from same mesh, and if so where is my mistake? How can i make it ?

This is the amount of materials `WeaponGameObject` have:

[image]

Comment: Is this solved?

Comment: I am afraid not yet.

Comment: Like Cid said, you have no instantiation code.  You need that. Did you try that?

Comment: @Programmer i have tried that but still not working. I updated my question with the suggestion you provided.

Comment: What's the amount of material does your  WeaponGameObject object have? Can we see a screenshot of its MeshRenderer in the Inspector tab? Maybe what's going on in the scene?

Comment: I have made update on the question. Strangely the name appears as `1(Clone)(Clone)`. I have two instantiations for that mesh and they both take the textures of the last one instantiated.

Comment: Ok I need more code to leave an answer. Your current code will only instantiate one object only. I need to see the complete code for that

Comment: I have placed the code of the whole function.

Comment: Also to instantiate two objects. I just call twice `EquipItem` function.

Comment: @Programmer do you see any problem? Maybe the fact that the function is `static` can that be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible issue I see is the use of the `sharedMaterials` property:

```
foreach(Material mat in WeaponGameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterials)
```

The `sharedMaterials` is used to modify other instances of the material.

See [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterials.html):

> Modifying any material in sharedMaterials will change the appearance
>   of all objects using this material, and change material settings that
>   are stored in the project too.

It looks like you should use the [`materials`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html) property which will only modify the appearance of only that object.

```
foreach(Material mat in WeaponGameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials)
```

Comment: Now both of the gameobjects appear as white with no textures on them. Is there any mistake in the code of setting the textures ? I get no warning or whatsoever error. I tried `Debug.Log("MAT NAME: " + mat.name);` inside the foreach and it shows their names accordingly. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: The problem now is a different stuff. Click "Play" , select each shader you put in the screenshot, expand them and check if the textures are actually in the slots. Are the textures assigned? If they are not then the `Resources.Load` is failing. Separate the  `Resources.Load` code to assign the returned variable to temporary variable then check if they are null.

Comment: Thanks i found the problem. Both cases `Instantiate` and `.materials` instead of `sharedMaterias` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`WeaponGameObject` is an unique object if instantiated properly. You have to use `Instantiate()` to create new references to apply other textures.

In example :

```
public void applyTexture(string texture, GameObject WeaponGameObject)
{
    foreach(Material mat in WeaponGameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterials)
    {
        mat.color = Color.white;
        mat.SetTexture("_MainTex", Resources.Load("Wardrobe/Weapons/" + texture + "_" + mat.name + "_AlbedoTransparency") as Texture);
        mat.SetTexture("_MetallicGlossMap", Resources.Load("Wardrobe/Weapons/" + texture + "_MetallicSmoothness") as Texture);
        mat.SetTexture("_BumpMap", Resources.Load("Wardrobe/Weapons/" + texture + "_" + mat.name + "_Normal") as Texture);
        mat.SetTexture("_OcclusionMap", Resources.Load("Wardrobe/Weapons/" + texture + "_" + mat.name + "_AO") as Texture);
    }
}

GameObject WeaponGameObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Wardrobe/Weapons/" + iTemplate.model)) as GameObject;
GameObject WeaponGameObject2 = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Wardrobe/Weapons/" + iTemplate.model)) as GameObject;
GameObject WeaponGameObject3 = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Wardrobe/Weapons/" + iTemplate.model)) as GameObject;

if (iTemplate.texture != null)
    applyTexture(iTemplate.texture + "/" + iTemplate.model, WeaponGameObject);
if (iTemplate2.texture != null)
    applyTexture(iTemplate2.texture + "/" + iTemplate2.model, WeaponGameObject2);
if (iTemplate3.texture != null)
    applyTexture(iTemplate3.texture + "/" + iTemplate3.model, WeaponGameObject3);
```

Comment: Hello Cid. No it's not, the code you see is part of a function. Every time the function is called there is another instance of `WeaponGameObject`